# How to get Bounds of New Region made with PointsF?

Tags: c#

I am trying some simple collisions like this:

```
 if (Object1.bounds.intersectWith(Object2.bounds){ }
```

Now I am defining a new region for each object using pointsf like this :

```
using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
{
    // Create points that define polygon.
    PointF point1 = new PointF(this.Width/2, 0);
    PointF point2 = new PointF(this.Width, this.Height/2);
    PointF point3 = new PointF(this.Width / 2, this.Height);
    PointF point4 = new PointF(0, this.Height/2);

    PointF[] curvePoints =
             {
                 point1,
                 point2,
                 point3,
                 point4,
             };

    gp.AddLines(curvePoints.ToArray());
    this.Region = new Region(gp);
}
```

But, the intersectionWith statement is only detecting the rectangle bounds. I try a code similar to this but its not working, how can I get the new region boundaries (triangle) in order to make it work?

```
 if (Object1.region.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Object2.region.Bounds))
 (This doesn't work obviously);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: region1.Intersect(region2); if (!region1.isEmpty(gr).. It is rather slow for large regions

Comment: what is gr?sdasd

Comment: i am calling the code outside the paint event

Comment: You can look it up in MSDN to find that it is a valid Graphics object. You can always createGraphics one for this purpose, ie for measuring the pixels.